# Target specific resources with kustomize's PrefixSuffixTransformer

Tags: kubernetes, templating, kustomize

I'm trying to use a `PrefixSuffixTransformer` on specific resources using kustomize.

Let's say we have the following scenario :

```
.
├── base
│   ├── secrets.yaml
│   └── kustomization.yaml
└── dev
    ├── prefixer.yaml
    └── kustomization.yaml
```

**base/secrets.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: spv.no/v1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
  name: my-secret-1
spec:
  vault:
    name: my-vault
    object:
      name: foo
      type: secret 
  output:
    secret:
      name: foo
      dataKey: foo
---
apiVersion: spv.no/v1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
  name: my-secret-2
spec:
  vault:
    name: my-vault
    object:
      name: bar
      type: secret 
  output:
    secret:
      name: bar
      dataKey: bar
```

**base/kustomization.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - secrets.yaml
```

**dev/kustomization.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: dev-namespace
commonLabels:
    env: dev 
bases:
- ../base/
transformers:
  - prefixer.yaml
```

**dev/prefixer.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: builtin
kind: PrefixSuffixTransformer
metadata:
  name: envPrefixer
prefix: dev-
fieldSpecs:
  - kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
    path: spec/vault/object/name
```

How could I only apply to transformation on `my-secret-1` but not `my-secret-2` ?

I would like to generate all manifests in a single `kustomize build` call and avoid patching  every resources by their name as in real life I have way more resources than just 2 secrets.

I've tried to use component and different folder structure but no luck.

**Expected output :**

```yaml
apiVersion: spv.no/v1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
  name: my-secret-1
  labels:
    env: dev
  namespace: dev-namespace
spec:
  vault:
    name: my-vault
    object:
      name: dev-foo
      type: secret 
  output:
    secret:
      name: foo
      dataKey: foo
---
apiVersion: spv.no/v1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
  name: my-secret-2
  labels:
    env: dev
  namespace: dev-namespace
spec:
  vault:
    name: my-vault
    object:
      name: bar
      type: secret 
  output:
    secret:
      name: bar
      dataKey: bar
```

Comment: Did you finf a solution to this. I'm kinda in the same situation.

Comment: Nope - I've had to move those resources in another folder unfortunately